# autohotkey dropdown selection in a website not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, automation, html-select, autohotkey

I am working on a auto hot key script that can automate a drop down selection. I do not know what is happening but it seems to be failing. I have tried various method of getting it to read the information to the point of just adding a default value and it still will not change the value of the dropdown box.

Here is the start of the code.

```
url:= "first page"
URLElegibility := "Second Page"
counter := 0

Sleep 9000
; create ie instance
ie := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible := true  ; This is known to work incorrectly on IE7.

loginHL(url) ;login to the website
Sleep 2000 
SigningIn() ;Sign into site
loginHL(URLElegibility) ; log into second site this just pushes the site to go to a second link

selectObj := ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").options
Sleep 2500

selectItem := "bad"
While !(InStr(selectItem,"Value to Get")) ;
{
index := A_Index
selectItem := selectObj[A_Index].text

MsgBox "Error is here it goes on a infinite loop trying to find the value to get"
}
index := selectObj[index].value
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").value := index
```

I tried these methods next to change the dropdown with no success.

```
MsgBox "Slelected value"
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").focus()
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").value := 4
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").value = 4
Sleep 2500
MsgBox "Slelected index"
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").focus()
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").selectedIndex = 1
ie.document.getElementById("payerDropDown").selectedIndex := 4
Sleep 2500
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am looking at the tutorials and this should be working. Anyone with any advice on what I am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using `A_Index` without `Loop`. You appear to have an infinite loop because your while condition will never evaluate to `true`. Your example is incomplete so it's impossible for anyone to reproduce the problem you're describing. Presumably you're using `ComObjConnect` or some other method to connect to ie? And perhaps there is a problem with the HTML you're trying to access. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I Added the start and finish to the code. The A_Index I have seen used before for a selection drop down list in a form that is the reason why I use it. The while condition will turn true once selectItem from the dropdown equals the text I want. I then use the index to switch it into that index.

Comment: `A_Index` only works within a [Loop](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm). You don't have a `loop`, so you cannot use `A_Index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what ended up happening is that the web page uses forms. I was able to target the internal page within the form and from there fill out the information. Hard to believe that these html forms can be a small pain.